# I cannot attach fragment the second time arround

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am programatically creating fragment inside FrameLayout, and I'm displaying a map using googlemap. When I run it for the first time, it is showing the map. The problem is when I run it for the second time around it shows me a blank page. Does any of you have a workaround for this ? thanks

**my xml file is res/layout/activity_location**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

**Script**

```
 private void viewLocation()
{

    setTitle("Location");
    inflateView(frame, R.layout.activity_location);

    final String TAG = "map";
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    transaction.add(R.id.map_layout, mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(), TAG);
    transaction.commit();

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}
```

Comment: Use `replace(..)` instead of `add(...)`

Comment: already tried it but it gave me same result

Comment: Can you post your full code?